# Intermittent memory exception error with COM communication

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, serial-port

This code is for Windows 7. I am trying to grab the response to an AT command and print just the part of the string I need. Visual Studio Express is randomly telling me I have memory exceptions with this code. It doesn't happen every time.

```
#include <Windows.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    HANDLE hSerial = CreateFile("COM3",GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,0,0,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);

    if(hSerial==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        std::cout << "Insert error message";

    DCB dcbSerialParams = {0};
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength=sizeof(dcbSerialParams);

    if (!GetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams)) 
        std::cout << "Insert error message";

    dcbSerialParams.BaudRate=CBR_9600;
    dcbSerialParams.ByteSize=8;
    dcbSerialParams.StopBits=ONESTOPBIT;
    dcbSerialParams.Parity=NOPARITY;

    if (!SetCommState(hSerial,&dcbSerialParams))
        std::cout << "Insert error message";


    COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts={0};
    timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout=50;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant=50;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier=10;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant=50;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier=10;
    if(!SetCommTimeouts(hSerial, &timeouts))
        std::cout << "Insert error message";



while(1)
{
char szBuff[50+1] = {0};
char wzBuff[14] = {"AT+CSQ\r"};

DWORD dZBytesRead = 0;
DWORD dwBytesRead = 0;


if(!WriteFile(hSerial, wzBuff, 7, &dZBytesRead, NULL))
    std::cout << "Write error";

if(!ReadFile(hSerial, szBuff, 50, &dwBytesRead, NULL))
    std::cout << "Read Error";



std:: cout << szBuff;
std::string test = std::string(szBuff).substr(8,10);
std::cout << test;
Sleep(500);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well all the program does is output text so I change nothing.

Comment: You are arguing about semantics

Comment: Maybe, but it's a pet peeve of mine when people blame "randomness" for bugs in their own code and don't admit to even themselves when what they have written is broken.

Comment: I stated that it is throwing errors -therefor I am aware it is broken. I was stating that the errors are semi random meaning that it is hard for me to single out what exactly is calling it. Please keep your petty complaints to yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in iterator debugging is going to complain about your substr() call.  You are making some wrong assumptions:

- ReadFile() will only return what's available in the serial port receive buffer.  Serial ports are slow, you typically only get one or two characters.  You cannot ignore dwBytesRead.
- A serial port doesn't return C strings, it returns bytes.  You won't get the zero terminator.  Use dwBytesRead again to append the zero yourself.

Keep calling ReadFile() until you've received the full response.  Typically terminated by a line feed character.  Then process the response.